# How to avoid fliplr in the below code?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to split a region in an image into left and right. But I am avoiding a certain percentage of columns in the center from each side.

So,
I have to get the keep indexes for both left and right.

I am using `fliplr` to reverse array indexes of right side,

get (1:n_indices),

then again `fliplr` back to normal.

Can I avoid `fliplr` in the below code:

```
img1 = imread('sample4.png');
keepPercent = 0.9; %90 on both sides
columnsWithAllZeros = all(img1 == 0);

left_idx = find(~columnsWithAllZeros,1,'first');
right_idx = find(~columnsWithAllZeros,1,'last');

cent_idx = floor(mean([left_idx,right_idx]));
left_to_cent_idxs = left_idx:cent_idx;
cent_to_right_idxs = cent_idx+1:right_idx;
cent_to_right_idxs = fliplr(cent_to_right_idxs); % flip

num_leftKeep_idxs = floor(keepPercent *length(left_to_cent_idxs));
num_rightKeep_idxs = floor(keepPercent *length(cent_to_right_idxs));

right_keepImg_idxs = left_to_cent_idxs(1:num_leftKeep_idxs);
left_keepImg_idxs = cent_to_right_idxs(1:num_rightKeep_idxs);
left_keepImg_idxs = fliplr(left_keepImg_idxs); %flip back This is not needed I Know

[leftBrain_img, rightBrain_img]  = deal(zeros(nrow, ncol, 'logical'));
leftBrain_img(:,left_keepImg_idxs) = img1(:,left_keepImg_idxs);
rightBrain_img(:,right_keepImg_idxs) = img1(:,right_keepImg_idxs);

rightBrain_img = cast(rightBrain_img,'uint16') .*img1;
leftBrain_img = cast(leftBrain_img,'uint16') .*img1;
figure,
subplot(131), imshow(img1,[])
subplot(132), imshow(rightBrain_img,[])
subplot(133), imshow(leftBrain_img,[])
```

The sample image is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JPmQnkneBKo8RYDd3jarB2qefYv214-I/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks,

Gopi

Comment: Have you tried `cent_to_right_idxs = right_idx : -1: cent_idx+1;`?

Comment: @rahnema1, It works Thanks. I am looking to see if Matlab has a numpy equivalent of something like `num_list[-9:]`

Comment: The tweak you suggested solves my problem and good

Comment: This is what I am looking for, but your answer looks more readable, `left_keepImg_idxs = cent_to_right_idxs(end-num_rightKeep_idxs+1:end)`

Comment: You can use this `num_list(end-9+1:end)` as an equivalent to the example.

Comment: Thanks @rahnema1

Answer (score 0):

That could be done, just like @rahnema1 said. But the question is why even do it when it could be done in a much faster & simpler way! 
Have a look at this code-

```
img1 = imread('sample4.png');
keepPercent = 0.9; %90 on both sides
columnsWithAllZeros = all(img1 == 0);
leavepercent=1-keepPercent;
idx=minmax(find(columnsWithAllZeros==0));

cent_idx = floor(mean(idx));
left_keepImg_idxs1=idx(1):cent_idx-floor(leavepercent*(cent_idx-idx(1)+1));
right_keepImg_idxs1=cent_idx+1+floor(leavepercent*(idx(2)-cent_idx+1)):idx(2);

[leftBrain_img, rightBrain_img]  =deal(zeros(512, 512, 'logical'));
leftBrain_img(:,left_keepImg_idxs1) = img1(:,left_keepImg_idxs1);
rightBrain_img(:,right_keepImg_idxs1) = img1(:,right_keepImg_idxs1);

rightBrain_img = cast(rightBrain_img,'uint16') .*img1;
leftBrain_img = cast(leftBrain_img,'uint16') .*img1;
figure,
subplot(131), imshow(img1,[])
subplot(132), imshow(rightBrain_img,[])
subplot(133), imshow(leftBrain_img,[])
```

Comment: It works as expected, but I am looking to see if I can do indexing from the end like numpy. `num_list[-9:]`